# Python convert list of multiple words to single words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a list of words for example:

`words = ['one','two','three four','five','six seven']` # quote was missing

And I am trying to create a new list where each item in the list is just one word so I would have:

`words = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']`

Would the best thing to do be join the entire list into a string and then tokenize the string? Something like this:

`word_string = ' '.join(words)
tokenize_list = nltk.tokenize(word_string)`

Or is there a better option?

Comment: anything wrong with `' '.join(words).split(' ')`?

Comment: @EdChum thats a pretty good answer i think

Comment: The only other solution I can think of is tokenize each item separately and joining back the results. I think your solution is better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can join using a space separator and then split again:

```
In [22]:

words = ['one','two','three four','five','six seven']
' '.join(words).split()
Out[22]:
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
```

Comment: Trivial suggestion: you could call `split()` with no argument to save three characters.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Hmm. I thought I did try that and it failed but it does actually work, will update thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
words = ['one','two','three four','five','six seven']
```

With a loop:

```
words_result = []
for item in words:
    for word in item.split():
        words_result.append(word)
```

or as a comprehension:

```
words = [word for item in words for word in item.split()]
```

Comment: You have a good point: in my version, `word` might not actually be a word. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with a slight use of regular expressions:

```
import re

words = ['one','two','three four','five','six seven']
result = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', str(words))
```