# Quickest way to get unique values

Tags: python

I want to get the unique language codes from a list, but it's proving more difficult that I imagined as it's mixed with unicode and strings:

```
set([u'RU', u'FR', u'EN', u'PT', u'AR, CS, DA, DE, FI, FR, HE, NO, PL, PT, SL, SV, TH, TR, ZH', u'DE', u'TR', u'IT', u'DE, FR', u'TH', u'JA'])
```

How would I get the set of unique language codes here?

Comment: `u'AR, CS, DA, DE, FI, FR, HE, NO, PL, PT, SL, SV, TH, TR, ZH'`?

Comment: for each element try to split and re-add? you have a really high python score, so what is the difficulty exactly?

Comment: @Trilarion got it, thanks

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085694/python-convert-list-of-multiple-words-to-single-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input always looks the same as your example, your can split the several-long items before creating your set:

```
uniques = set(x for x in names.split(u', ') for names in input_list)
```